# How to match regular expression exactly in R and pull out pattern

Tags: regex, r

I want to get pattern from my vector of strings

```
string <- c(
  "P10000101 - Przychody netto ze sprzedazy produktów" ,                    
  "P10000102_PL - Przychody nettozy uslug",                     
  "P1000010201_PL - Handlowych, marketingowych, szkoleniowych",             
  "P100001020101 - - Handlowych,, szkoleniowych - refaktury",
  "- Handlowych, marketingowych,P100001020102, - pozostale"
)
```

As result I want to get exact match of regular expression

```
result <- c(
  "P10000101",
  "P10000102_PL",
  "P1000010201_PL",
  "P100001020101",
  "P100001020102"
)
```

I tried with this `pattern  = "([PLA]\\d+)"` and different combinations of `value = T, fixed = T, perl = T.`

```
grep(x = string, pattern = "([PLA]\\d+(_PL)?)", fixed = T)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can try with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, "P\\d+(_[A-Z]+)*")
#[1] "P10000101"      "P10000102_PL"   "P1000010201_PL" "P100001020101"  "P100001020102"
```

---

`grep` is for finding whether the match pattern is present in a particular string or not.  For extraction, either use `sub` or `gregexpr/regmatches` or `str_extract`

Using the `base R` (`regexpr/regmatches`)

```
regmatches(string, regexpr("P\\d+(_[A-Z]+)*", string))
#[1] "P10000101"      "P10000102_PL"   "P1000010201_PL" "P100001020101"  "P100001020102"
```

Basically, the pattern to match is `P` followed by one more numbers (`\\d+`) followed by greedy (`*`) match of `_` and one or more upper case letters.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is perfect answer. Did not know earlier str_extract from stringr package. After EDIT regmatches also is working.

Comment: You can remove ``\`` before `_`, since a `_` is a "word" char.

Comment: The development version of `R` will have native support for this with `strcapture`

See:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/strcapture.html

And:
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html